# save date with DatePickerFlyout

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

i have a textblock in my windows 10 universal App.

when user tap on my textblock, my app should open date picker. then save selected Time to a string.

I tried this code:

```
 var picker = new DatePickerFlyout();
    await flyflow.ShowAtAsync(zing);
    var date = picker.Date;
string j = date.tostring("MMMM dd, yy");
```

i change date and click on ok button of date picker, but this don't save new date to date value.
zing is name of my Grid.
what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what's the question exactly?

Comment: @doctorBroctor how can i open date and time picker tools in button event?

Comment: why do you need separate buttons? The controls are designed that you can interact with them by tapping them directly. Also, depending on the device the app is running on the controls may not display a full screen picker.

Comment: @MattLacey my problem is i can open datepiker with code to choose a date!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written even a single line of code before coming on here? Perhaps you should learn how to fish, instead of going into another camp begging for handouts.

Comment: @Krythic yes, I tried.

Comment: So where is your code? Show us what you have done.

Comment: @Krythic I edited it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you initialize a new `DatePickerFlyout` named `picker` and use it to get the date picked by user. But you never show this date picker, you show a `DatePickerFlyout` named `flyflow` which may be defined in your XAML. So `picker.Date` will always be the default value as you didn't pick a date on it.

To solve your problem, you can just change `flyflow` to `picker` or use `flyflow.Date` to get the date picked by user:

```
await flyflow.ShowAtAsync(zing);
var date = flyflow.Date;
string j = date.ToString("MMMM dd, yy");
```